# Why is my doubly-linked list repeating on insertion?

Tags: java

My code is generating odd answers that I can't entirely comprehend. For example, my insert method seems to just repeat the first insert that I make, disregarding the size of the list and any insert calls I make after it.

```
public class LinkedListImpl implements LIST_Interface {
        Node sentinel; 
        private int numElts;


public LinkedListImpl(){
        sentinel=new Node(0);
        numElts = 0;
    }

public boolean insert(double elt, int index) {
    Node temp = new Node(elt);
    Node currentNode;
    int x;

    if(index > size()) {
        return false;
    }   
    else  if(index == 0){
        currentNode = sentinel;
        if(size() == 0) {
            currentNode.prev = temp;
            temp.next = sentinel;
        }
        currentNode.next = temp;
        temp.prev = currentNode;

        numElts++;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        currentNode = sentinel;
        for(x = 0; x < index; x++) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        temp = currentNode;
        currentNode.prev = temp;
        temp.next = currentNode;

        numElts++;
        return true;
    }
}

public double get(int index) {
    Node currentNode;
    int x;

    if(numElts == 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    else {
        currentNode = sentinel;
        for(x = 0; x < index; x++) {
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return currentNode.getData();
    }
}
}
public int size() {
        return numElts;
    }
```

This code here:

```
LinkedListImpl L= new LinkedListImpl();
L.insert(45.0,  0);
L.insert(13.0, 1);
L.insert(89, 2);
System.out.println("Size of the list: " + L.size());
System.out.println(L.get(0));
System.out.println(L.get(1));
System.out.println(L.get(2));
System.out.println(L.get(3));
```

Returns:

```
Size of the list: 3
0.0
45.0
45.0
```

I don't understand why 45.0 isn't the first entry at `L.get(0)`

I also don't understand why it's duplicating the 45.0 over and over again. If I use  a for loop to print `L.get(x)` for `0 <= x <= 10` it will still repeat 45.0 all the way from `x = 2` to `x = 10`.

Comment: Just for the record: what is the point of having that index parameter, when you are using the method in an "add()" manner anyway?

Comment: Your #insert is riddled with logic errors. If the list size is `> 0` you make a self-referring loop on the last node in the list. If the list is a size of `0`, you make your existing sentinel value loop on the newly inserted element (both elements are linked to each other via both `next`/`prev`). Lastly, your sentinel is being treated as an actual value within the list. You need to either account for the sentinel consistently or get rid of it (e.g. setting `null` for an empty list).

Comment: @Rogue could you explain each of your points a little more? I don't see the self-referring loop, nor do I see the sentinel loop. I'm also not sure how to treat the sentinel if not in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you are not setting all of the references. To insert `newNode` into a doubly-linked linked between `prevNode` and `nextNode`, to you need to change the following references:

```
prevNode.next
newNode.prev
newNode.next
nextNode.prev
```

Your code only sets a subset of those.